# Can anyone explain what Linea mainnet is and does

Tags: blockchain, metamask, web3-providers

"Linea is a network that scales the experience of Ethereum. Its out-of-the-box compatibility with the Ethereum Virtual Machine enables the deployment of already-existing applications, as well as the creation of new ones that would be too costly on Mainnet. It also enables the community to use those dapps, at a fraction of the cost, and at multiples the speed of Mainnet." This is on the website and i can't understand how or what it does, tried to look for some videos but there aren't any. It could be a stupid question but i am new to web3.

Answer (score 0):

Ever been stuck in Bangalore or Delhi's traffic? Ethereum's main network can feel just like that – slow and costly. Linea is your solution – imagine it as a dedicated fast lane on India's highways. It offers quicker transactions and lower costs, seamlessly integrating with Ethereum. Developers can migrate existing dapps to Linea effortlessly and create new ones optimized for its efficiency. Essentially, Linea acts as a valuable extension of Ethereum, reducing congestion while maintaining security and ease of use.